# Using pgadmin with nginx in docker containers

Tags: django, docker, nginx, reverse-proxy, pgadmin

I felt into issues configuring environment, containing postgres, pgadmin and nginx. All this services are in docker containers and here is my docker-compose file:

```
version: '3'

services:
  postgres:
    image: postgres
    environment:
      POSTGRES_USER: postgres
      POSTGRES_PASSWORD: postgres

  pgadmin:
    links:
      - postgres:postgres
    image: dpage/pgadmin4:3.0
    environment:
      PGADMIN_DEFAULT_EMAIL: 'postgres@pg.com'
      PGADMIN_DEFAULT_PASSWORD: 'postgres'
    ports:
      - "5050:80"
    restart: unless-stopped

  nginx:
    links:
      - pgadmin:pgadmin
    image: "nginx:1.13.12"
    ports:
      - "80:80"
    volumes:
      - ./nginxServers/server:/etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf
```

And here is my `nginx.conf`, placed in `./nginxServers/server`:

```
server {
    listen       80;
    server_name  _;

    location  /pgadmin/ {                                                                    
            proxy_pass http://pgadmin/;
    }
}
```

As you can see, it's a very simple setup, allowing me to use pgadmin via http://localhost/pgadmin.

Unfortunately, this doesn't work. I can see pgadmin web interface via http://127.0.0.1:5050, but when i navigate to http://127.0.0.1/pgadmin, all the styles and scripts are not loaded.

I also tried another location in nginx configuration:

```
location  /pgadmin {                                                                    
            proxy_pass http://pgadmin;
}
```

But this also didn't help.

Thus, i'm stucked with correct configuration of nginx as a reverse proxy for pgadmin.

P.S. As i've googled, this problem can be with serving django static content, but since i'm not familiar with django, i can't get any workaround.

I'll be gratefull for any help with this strange problem.

Comment: Have you defined any `docker network`?

Comment: @AlexGalera No i didn't, as you can see, i simply use container name as host name and it works. Is this a reason of my problem?

Comment: Please, try with `network: host` for docker-compose, or if you launch it with docker, `docker run --net=host...`

Comment: @AlexGalera So i deleted links and added `network_mode: "host"` and now it doesn't work at all, because nginx can't find hostname pgadmin. What did you want me to do with `net=host`? I'm not very good with docker-compose yet

Comment: If you launch a container with `docker run --net=host` option, container inherits all network configuration of the host. So, is possible to share eth interfaces, including localhost. In docker-compose, section is called: `network-mode: "host"`. Let me post in an answer, so you can see better structured the code.

Comment: @AlexVoskresenskiy did you manage to get this working. I am trying to do the exact same thing.

Comment: @GeyerBisschoff unfortunately, i didn't get this working.

Answer (score 2):

Probably you already solved it. But the problem is the way nginx resolves the hostname. It does that only once for performance reasons. To force nginx to search for the ip dynamically, just add the Docker resolver in the nginx configuration

```
http {
  resolver 127.0.0.11 ipv6=off;
}
```

see here at the bottom: [docker dns server](https://docs.docker.com/v17.09/engine/userguide/networking/configure-dns/)